# The xamarin essentials - WebAuthenticator - err_unknown_url_scheme

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webauthenticator

[image]I get a exception when use method : await WebAuthenticator.AunthenticateAsync(new Uri(url), new Uri("myapp:///"));

I get the exception  after login successful on web page.
What mistake?

[image]

Comment: did you register your custom url scheme as directed in the "Get Started" docs?

Comment: Hi, @Jason ! Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was in browse "Chrome".